# Show guest memory utilisation in vCenter

Tags: vmware-esxi, memory-usage, vmware-vcenter

Is it possible to record and show the amount of memory that a Windows guest OS is using in vCenter? In [this](https://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2013/10/understanding-vsphere-active-memory.html) blog post VMware recommends using the guest OS memory counter for capacity planning. However, the metric plots in vCenter are much more convenient for showing trends and longer term monitoring than just opening Task Manager.

From this blog post:

> I personally believe the best memory counters are those from the guest operating systems as they truly represent what is allocated and idle.  We need to manage memory from the guest perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm being dim here but do you literally mean how much memory is a VM actually using, or do you mean how do I find out how much memory a VM *thinks* it's using?

If the former - which by the way is a far more realistic result than the quote you used suggests - then it's just under the Monitor/Performance tab for the VM in vCenter - select memory and maybe a custom range and you're done.

If the latter then the guest OS is what you need, perfmon probably, but it's not what memory is really being used, just what the VM thinks it is.

If you meant something else you'll have to clarify sorry.